# File not found exception for DDL file during runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

So I have a solution with 3 projects. One of the projects is built as a class library and is referencing a third party DLL. When I am building the solution everything is just fine. However, when I run the program and call a method inside my class library I get a "File not found" exception for the referenced third party DLL.

When I look in the output folder I can see the DLL. 
I also tried to load it using:

```
Assembly.LoadFile("absolutePathToFileInOutputFolder")
```

Still getting the same exception. But if I use the path to another copy of the DLL it works.
So what could be the reason for this behaviour? Can it be that one of my projects are locking the DLL for the other projects?

Comment: did you manually add the dll to the References node in the project..? also make sure that the `CopyToLocal = true` is set for that .dll reference.
if you are using a single solution with 3 projects I would suggest creating a Dependency folder, and put all your dll's there and then remove the references and re-add them, pointing to the dependency folder..

Comment: @MethodMan Yes I used "Add reference" and browsed for it. Regarding the Dependency folder that might be good idea for later.

Comment: why wait for later.. at least if you have all of the dependent dll's in one folder that can be accessed by all 3 projects in the same solution.. you wouldn't have this problem and or issue.. in regards to the 3rd Party DLLS

Comment: @Methodman I don't see how this would solve my problem. Sure it is nice and tidy but it will not change the fact that my project is unable to load the DLL.

Comment: perhaps you should try it.. also this could be a .Config file entry issue as well please do not knock something until you try it.. good luck `absolutePathToFileInOutputFolder` is that the name of the Actual dll did you check it for Case and spelling..?

Answer (score 0):

This is a recurrent issue once in a while in Visual Studio. Usually it corrects itself setting the reference to said DLL on the Properties Window with `CopyToLocal = True`.

Comment: As I said, the file is already in the output folder so that is not the problem. Also CopyToLocal is already true.